# Holding times in a database: STRING vs TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, database-design, timestamp

I have a database that each entry is a business, some of the data is opening and closing times. Originally, to support multiple opening and closing times in a day I was going to store it as a string such as: '09:00-15:00,17:00-22:00' and then split it up and convert it to TIMESTAMPS server-side. I now understand that it is "bad form" to store times as strings. But the solution requires a second table.

What exactly is the issue with using a string instead of DATE or TIMESTAMP? If I kept it all in one table it would get pulled with my current query and then just processed and converted into a TIMESTAMP. Using multiple tables causes more queries. Is the string manipulation and conversion really that much more taxing than another query searching through an entire table that will end up with thousands of entries?

Comment: Are these opening and closing times independent of any date?  It is a bad idea to store CSV time data, but without knowing more of your problem I can't comment further.

Comment: Independent of dates, yes. But they will be matched up with days of the week. Why is it such a bad idea to store CSV data in such a manner?

Comment: Databases have date functions which often only work on dates.  By using text you undermine much of the power which your database offers.

Comment: But if I'm not using these functions is it really such a bad idea? I'm more interested in the PHP time functions which I can convert the string into.

Comment: That's probably bad practice.  Let MySQL handle the data side of things if possible

Comment: Can MySQL do algorithms to determine if a 24 hour store is open? All research I did on this subject showed to do this with a programming language, not MySQL. Other than that it is for displaying to the user. Either way, my question is not what should I do, it's why? Why should I use TIMESTAMP and MySQL instead of strings and PHP? I understand this is the "norm," but why?

Comment: I still don't know enough to answer.  If you had a series of date ranges and you wanted to find overlaps, this is relatively easy in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three separate issues here.  One is whether it is better to combine two elementary data items into a list, and store the list in one place, or to keep the elementary items separate, and store them in two separate places.  For these purposes, I'm considering the intersection of a single row and a single column to be one place.

The second issue is whether it is better to identify a time interval as a single elementary item or better to describe a time interval as two elementary items, side by side.

The third issue is whether it is better to store points in time as strings or use the DBMS timestamp datatype.

For the first issue, it's better to store separate elementary items in separate places.  In this case, in two separate rows of the same table.

For the second issue, it's better to describe a time interval as two timestamps side by side than to combine them into an interval, for the DBMS systems I have used.  But there are DBMS systems that have a time interval datatype that is distinct from the timestamp datatype.  Your mileage may vary.

For the third issue, it's better to use the DBMS timestamp  datatype to describe a point in time than a character string.  Different DBMS products have different facilities for storing a time without any date associated with it, and in  your case, you may want to make use of this.  It depends on how you will be searching the data.  If you are going to want to find all the rows that contain a 9:00 to 15:00 time range regardless of date, you will want to make use of this.  If you are going to want to find all the rows that contain a 9:00 to 15:00 range on any Tuesday, I suggest you look into data warehousing techniques.

Why?

For the first two answers, it has to do with normalization, indexing, searching strategies, and query optimization.  These concepts are all related, and  each of them will help you understand the other three.

For the third answer, it has to do with using the power of the DBMS to do the detailed work for you.  Any good DBMS will have tools for subtracting timestamps to yield a time interval,  and for ordering timestamps correctly. Getting the DBMS to do this work for you will save you a  lot of work in your application programming,  and generally use less computer resources in production.

Having said that, I don't know mySQL, so I don't know how good it is for date manipulations or for query optimization.

Comment: Thank you. I think in the end what it really boils down to is that in my current situation the string solution would be a quicker and easier solution without affecting the end user, I'm not doing much with time manipulation right now and a lot of the coding you say it would relieve me of is already written. But I can see how, with future updates, this could pose an issue. I am new to advanced database handling and such and will definitely research the topics you listed. Many thanks for addressing my question of why rather than how.

Answer (score 0):

By `'09:00-15:00,17:00-22:00'`, you mean that it is open for two periods of time?  Then 2 rows in one table.  If the open times vary by day of week, then another column to specify that.  If you want holidays, another column.

But... What will you be doing with the data?...

If you are going to write SQL to use the times, then what I described may work best.

If the processing will be in your application code, then a CSV file that you load every time, parse every time, etc, may be best.

Or, you could put that CSV file into a table as one big string.  (However, this is not much different than having a file.)

Comment: Yes, I mean those would be open time periods in a single day. The current structure I came up with is basically what you described. But my old system had two columns for each day of the week of value TIMESTAMP. But this doesn't support multiple times in a single day. Instead I would have a single column for each day of the week that would be strings. As far as what I'm doing with this data. It gets processed on the server to be displayed to the user, looking for businesses. It also will be used to determine if the business is open. (I already have these functions)

Comment: You could use the datatype `TIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three separate issues here.  One is whether it is better to combine two elementary data items into a list, and store the list in one place, or to keep the elementary items separate, and store them in two separate places.  For these purposes, I'm considering the intersection of a single row and a single column to be one place.

The second issue is whether it is better to identify a time interval as a single elementary item or better to describe a time interval as two elementary items, side by side.

The third issue is whether it is better to store dates as strings or use the DBMS timestamp datatype.

For the first issue, it's better to store separate elementary items in separate places.  In this case, in two separate rows of the same table.

For the second issue, it's better to describe a time interval as two timestamps side by side than to combine them into an interval, for the DBMS systems I have used.  But there are DBMS systems that have a time interval datatype that is distinct from the timestamp datatype.  You mileage may vary.

For the third issue, it's better to use the DBMS timestamp  datatype to describe a point in time than a character string.  Different DBMS products have different facilities for storing a time without any date associated with it, and in  your case, you may want to make use of this.  It depends on how you will be searching the data.  If you are going to want to find all the rows that contain a 9:00 to 15:00 time range regardless of date, you will want to make use of this.  If you are going to want to find all the rows that contain a 9:00 to 15:00 range on any Tuesday, I suggest you look into data warehousing techniques.

Why do I gove these answers?

For the first two answers, it has to do with normalization, indexing, and searching efficiency.  These concepts are all related, and you should learn them all at about the same time, because each of them will help you understand the other two.

For the third answer, it has to do with using the power of the DBMS to do the detailed work for you.  Any good DBMS will have tools for subtracting timestamps to yield a time interval,  and for ordering timestamps correctly. Getting the DBMS to do this work for you will save you a  lot of work in your application programming,  and generally use less computer resources in production.